# Effective ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview

First of all, my **problem:**
My `ListView` woun't scroll smoothly.

Now a bunch of **details:**

I'm currently using an `ArrayAdapter<CustomClass>` in my App for displaying Text and and Image in each element of the `ListView`. I've been trying to make the `ListView` to scroll as smooth as possible. But as soon as the text becomes longer (about 40 characters), the `ListView` starts to stutter when scrolling.
I am displaying about 9 rows at the same time. If I make the `ListView` smaller (about 6 rows) it works fine..
I am not implementing `onScrollListener` and I am not running big background tasks.

This is the code I'm currently using (only getView and Holder):

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    //View row = convertView;
    Holder holder = null;

    if(convertView == null){
        //Log.e("adapter", "convertview == null");
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();

        convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new Holder();
        holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.folder_name);
        holder.txtInfo = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.info_text);
        holder.pBar = (ProgressBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.pBar);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    }else{
        holder = (Holder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    TrackInfo tInfo = data.get(position);

    if(tInfo == null){
        return convertView;
    }      

    holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(icon);
    holder.txtTitle.setText(tInfo.getTitle());


    return convertView;
}

static class Holder
{
    ImageView imgIcon;
    TextView txtTitle;
    TextView txtInfo;
    ProgressBar pBar;
}
```

You may notice there are more elements than I actively use. This is due to the reason that I normally use the others, too, but I am currently ignoring them since I was trying to find out why it's not scrolling smoothly.
As already mentioned, it seems to be the length of the string `tInfo.getTitle()`. I can't change the length of the strings, since those are filenames I can't influence.

Now my **QUESTION:**
What's the problem? Is it that much data to handle? Or is my code bad?
I'm testing on a Moto G (1.2GHz Quad-Core, [more details here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moto_G)).

Thank you for your attention, have a good flight!

Comment: Use Traceview and determine where your problem lies.

Comment: Okay, thanks. This looks like something I have to get into first, but looks pretty informative, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was working with `marquee` effect in the `ListView`. I always thought that as long as I don't call `TextView.setSelected(true)`, this wouldn't cause any further processing. Therefore, I had   `android:ellipsize="marquee"` as a parameter for my `TextView` in the layout-file of the `ListView`-element, while only one to-be-highlighted element was set selected.

Apparently, I was wrong.

As long as the text wasn't too long for the given space (about 40 characters), there was no problem. But if the size of the text exceeded the given space, the problems started.
I am not sure what exactly the problem is, but after having a look into the source of the `TextView`, I recognized that there is a lot more to do when marquee is enabled:

- The `TextView` is faded out on the right side (instead of `...`)
- A `Spannable` is used as a `CharSequence`
- It needs to be checked if marquee should start
- ...

So long story short:

I removed marquee and `ListView` scrolls very smoothly.